# Can't solve serious partition problem after an accident in the GRUB menu

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning

I previously had a dual-boot with Windows7 and Ubuntu 11.04. I had partitioned my 320 GB hard-disk into to partitions with about 100 GB for Ubuntu and the rest was reserved for Win7. I then upgraded to 11.10 and everything worked just fine.

My problems started when I accidentally choose the wrong option in the grub menu. I imagine it was something like the Windows Recovery-option because it led me to the "Acer eRecovery System Manager". The computer worked for sometime and came up with these three options (not sure if these were the exact words, but still) :

1. Delete all on the hard-disk and reset the computer to factory
   default settings.
2. Save all personal data and then reset the computer to factory default settings.
3. Exit.

As I just wanted to boot Windows I opted for choice number 3 (exit). The computer then shut down and when I started it up again I got the grub-rescue menu.

I then got into a lot of problems, but I managed to save all my documents from the Win7 and Ubuntu partitions by using a LiveCD for Ubuntu 11.04. At this moment GParted told my that the old partition reserved for Ubuntu was unallocated, but it still showed me the Win7 partition.

At the moment I got the Windows 7 up and running, but I want to get back to Ubuntu !!

So that was a long story, but I thought it may be important.

I have partially abandoned the idea of getting back to Ubuntu as before, so now I'm trying to install Ubuntu 11.10 from a LiveCD.

When I get to the Installation Type in the install menu I get this :
(edit : figured out I'm not allowed to post images...)

The menu shows that I may only chose the /dev/sda which has 320.1 GB.

GParted gives me this: (edit: figured out I'm not allowed to post images)

Gparted shows that I got no partitions and the whole /dev/sda section is **unallocated** (298.09 GB).

So where have my partitions gone now
`They have to be there somewhere because`sudo fdisk -l` gives me this :

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x93859385

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    24578047    12288000   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda2   *    24578048    24782847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        24782848   508650024   241933588+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       508650030   625153409    58251690    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       508651520   616964095    54156288   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       616966144   625141743     4087800   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

So my question is : what should I do to get installed Ubuntu on my computer as before ?
It doesn't really bother me if I have to reinstall Ubuntu, but if you think it's possible to save the old version lost somewhere on my hard-disk I'd be grateful :-D

Here are some information about my CPU :

```
    ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
    processor   : 0
    vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
    cpu family  : 6
    model       : 23
    model name  : Genuine Intel(R) CPU           U4100  @ 1.30GHz
    stepping    : 10
    cpu MHz     : 1200.000
    cache size  : 2048 KB
    physical id : 0
    siblings    : 2
    core id     : 0
    cpu cores   : 2
    apicid      : 0
    initial apicid  : 0
    fpu     : yes
    fpu_exception   : yes
    cpuid level : 13
    wp      : yes
    flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov         pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm         constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor         ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm xsave lahf_lm dts
    bogomips    : 2593.34
    clflush size    : 64
    cache_alignment : 64
    address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
    power management:

    processor   : 1
    vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
    cpu family  : 6
    model       : 23
    model name  : Genuine Intel(R) CPU           U4100  @ 1.30GHz
    stepping    : 10
    cpu MHz     : 1200.000
    cache size  : 2048 KB
    physical id : 0
    siblings    : 2
    core id     : 1
    cpu cores   : 2
    apicid      : 1
    initial apicid  : 1
    fpu     : yes
    fpu_exception   : yes
    cpuid level : 13
    wp      : yes
    flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov         pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm         constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor         ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm xsave lahf_lm dts
    bogomips    : 2593.48
    clflush size    : 64
    cache_alignment : 64
    address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
    power management:
```

Comment: Is your question still valid? If not please post your answer or solution and accept the answer, or delete your question. This is to help with the **Ask Ubuntu Clean Up** project. Thanks!

Comment: Please post the output of `sudo parted -l`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds as if your partition table is corrupt. I would try running testdisk

You can run it from the ubuntu live CD, you will need to install it first.

Testdisk is in the universe repositories.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

Here is a [Test Disk Walkthrough](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step)

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I finally had a enough time to try out testdisk, and it didn't change anything... I still see the partitions, but I'm not sure how to figure out if their damaged or not. After I write the new partitions table and reboot, I'm still at square one.

Comment: edit : I forgot to mention that I do see 4 devices in Nautilus (Systems Reserved and ACER for Win7, 55 GB for the ancient Linux partition and a mysterious PQSERVICE). But I still don't detect the partitions with GParted nor when trying to reinstall Ubuntu from the Live CD.